# AngularJs calling Controller from another one in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angular-directive

I have a `Controller A`, which is responsible for displaying data in `<body>`.
I also have another `Controller B`, which is located in directive for displaying navigation.

I'd like to pass data received from `Controller B` (say an array of strings) to `Controller A`, then make `Controller A` call method to bind data to the body.

So far, I've figured out one dirty soluton: to store data inside a var variable in my module and access it with button click.

Is there any other way of making `Controller B` influence `Controller A`?

Here's my code:

```
app.controller("Controller A", function($scope, $http){});

app.directive("Navigation", [function(){
return {
  restrict: "E",
  templateUrl: "navigation.html"
};
  }])
.controller("Controller B", function($scope, $http){});
```

Thank you.

Comment: so why you are not using `Navigation` directive in your `controller A` directly

Comment: that `controller B` is not part of the directive at all. You can have your directive require `ngModel` so it can set the value directly.

Comment: I've tried to make this one on plunker, doesn't seem to be working :(
http://plnkr.co/edit/eKiO3HF8AZkw1vktOr9C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need something like this, for unrelated scopes you can use a service, or custom events. 
Luckily angular makes it very easy to work with custom events.

I [updated your plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/FFOE6qrXpri5UChfdpTH?p=preview)  to show how this is possible. Here is the crux:

In your directive you do this. Using the $rootScope makes certain the event reaches your entire app.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('navClick','data send')
```

Then where you need to listen to it you do something like:

```
$scope.$on('navClick', function(ev,data) {console.log(data)})
```

Use this technique sparsely. Overusing this make it hard to follow the logic in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a callback function in your directive which will be invoked by the directive's controller whenever you have some data to pass:

```
app.directive("navigation", [function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        cb: '&cb',
        templateUrl: "navigation.html"
    };
}])
.controller("Controller B", function($scope, $http) {
    // Invoke the callback function passed to the directive
    // Of course this call can happen at any time of this
    // directive controller lifecycle
    $scope.cb('some data to pass to the callback function');
});
```

and then in the controller that has rendered the directive define this callback function:

```
app.controller("Controller A", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.callback = function(someData) {
        alert(someData);
    };
});
```

which will be passed when rendering the directive:

```
<div ng-navigation cb="callback"></div>
```

Now the directive controller can pass information to the original controller that rendered the directive.

Comment: To be honest I don't really understand the reasoning behind having the `&` case capability when the reference is easy using `=` but both work

Comment: Hmm, actually the difference is that `=` means an object whereas `&` means a function. My initial intent was to have a directive that accepts a function as parameter.

Comment: You are right, the object could have defined functions which can be invoked by the directive. I think that having 2 separate notions is making it a little bit more explicit as to what parameters the directive accepts. Otherwise you would have need to read the code of the directive in order to understand how exactly should be named the function on the passed object in order to be invoked. By having 2 separate constructs this is immediately clear by just looking at the directive definition.

Comment: Think I just figured it out. Can pass the parameters directly in the html

Comment: Does it suppose, that both Controller B and the directive must be inside the Controller A?

Comment: This will only work when the directive is inside the scope that controller a is in. If you need something for sibling scopes, this won't work.